# swift iOS - When moving speed = 0 ... image still spawns, how do I stop it?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm generating a 2D platform game where the object of the game is to jump over objects without causing a collision.  I've not written the code so once a collision takes place all scenery stops, that is except one object that spawns every second.  This spawning object is added in update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval).

Would anyone know how I can include this object to stop spawning when the collision is detected?

Thank you,

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

moving.addChild(trees)
moving.addChild(crow)

moving.addChild(cat)     //working (hero)
moving.addChild(sprite)  //working background
moving.addChild(dummy)   //working ground
moving.addChild(sprite)  //working skyline

}

func addCrow() {

// lots of code here
moving.addChild(crow)    // not working, still spawning when game stops

}

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


    if currentTime - self.lastCrowAdded > 1 {
        self.lastCrowAdded = currentTime + 1
        self.addCrow()               //wont allow me to change from self

    }
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if( moving.speed > 0 ) {
            moving.speed = 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change the condition in the if to also check if the speed is greater than 0.

Something like this:

`if currentTime - self.lastCrowAdded > 1 && moving.speed > 0`